# ExtJS 5 Grid Cell Width Calculation Wrong Using Flex

Tags: grid, width, cell, extjs5

After upgrading to ExtJS 5 from 4.2.1 I discovered a grid cell width calculation issue or what appears to be an issue.

Here is an example of the columns

```
columns: [
    { header: 'One', dataIndex: 'one', flex: 2 },
    { header: 'Two', dataIndex: 'two', flex: 2 },
    { header: 'Three', dataIndex: 'three', flex: 3 }
]
```

The headers fill the grid width as expected but grid cell widths are not equal to the headers in amounts of -5px / -5px / -12 px respectively.

The appearance is as if there is room for a scroll bar but the grid has only one row.
Grids that have enough data to have a scroll bar do not appear to have this issue.

Resizing the grid column puts things back in a proper alignment until new data is loaded and rendered again with the width calculations off. It re-sizes soon after a new data load.

I thought that maybe css was to blame but changing themes did not fix it nor did using ext-all.css rather than the debug css.

Is this a bug or have I missed a new config that will correct the width calculations?

> If this is a bug ... any suggestions for a work around?

Help much appreciated.

> UPDATE 1:
>
> I used Sencha Cmd to generate a basic app and created a grid view with the columns and a features.
> So far it looks like having a grouping feature seems to be the culprit.
> However, I do see the behavior on grids without a grouping feature.
> Those grids are in a border layout so I'll investigate that next.

Comment: It does seem like a bug, but it will be close to impossible to be definitive about it without a proper test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bug, however I discovered that wrapping `grid` with `container` with `auto` layout make fixes that issue (at least in my case).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nj4nk/3/

In example you can see 2 grids:

- first inside panel with `fit` layout - rows are narrower
- second inside panel with `auto` layout - rows are same as header

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much for the fix. Using layout: 'auto' has corrected the issue. How do I create my own jsfiddle to share?

Comment: Spent so much time trying to fix this. All I had to do is add `layout: 'auto'`. Thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Using layout:'auto' leaves scrolling broken. 
It appears that space is being reserved for the scrollbar, but setting reserveScrollbar:false doesn't help.